# How do i know if a thread is still working?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, pthreads, semaphore

I am currently working on a program where i use threads to go trough directories to find the total disk usage. I have a issue that I can't seem to find the answer to.

I have a function to see if the current directory contains another directory and if it does i want to push the path to the new directory on to a stack. This work is done by a thread, if the thread pushes up the path to a new directory another thread is going to search trough that directory.

The issue im having is to find the correct condition for the threads to work on, i want the threads to search for work (if there are any paths to search aka if there is any value on the stack) for as long as any thread is doing work.

Im thinking something like this:

```
While(any thread is working){
     while(stack != empty){
          do work
     }
     sleep()
}
```

I dont know how i can know if any of my threads are currently "doing work", is the easiest way to send in a work_complete flag or can i use semaphores for this. I can't really find any simular issue, just "simpler" examples when they use the threads to print/count something.

EDIT:

A more simple version of my question would be, how do i know if any of my threads are inside of the "do work" function?

Comment: You can use anything that keeps track of the number of threads working.

Comment: @g_bor Do you mind going into more depth of what you mean. To clarify my question i want to know if any thread is inside of "do work"

Comment: My pthreading is rusty but I believe something like `pthread_tryjoin_np` is what you are looking for. Basically poke a thread and see if it is alive, without blocking the poking thread. It's a gcc extension, so it is not portable (np).

Comment: If you want to know how many threads are inside a particular code section, just increment a shared counter when you enter it, and decrement the shared counter when you leave. I'm not sure it's the _best_ design, but it isn't hard. The counter can be a semaphore, or just an `_Atomic`.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for your answer! I don't think that exactly what im looking for since i don't want to terminate any of my threads if any of them are still working, or if im inside the outer while loop i want all of my threads to stay alive. As i understand it pthread_tryjoin_np only checks if they are terminated or not?

Comment: @Useless Thank you, seems to be what im looking for. I assume this would be thread safe if a mutex lock whenever i change that varible?

Comment: @forsb From what I remember you specify a timeout. Check with the `man`.

Comment: Mutex-protected counter will be safe, but possibly slow. If performance is a problem you can always switch to an atomic later though.

Comment: @Lundin Alright will read trough more proper, would be a really nice solution. Thanks again

Comment: Honestly, this looks like you're driving nails with a screwdrivers. It may "work", but... The placement of that `sleep` in conjunction with those stacked while-predicates screams to me that a properly managed predicate state and stack, protected by a mutex and signaled with a condition variable on state change, would be a proper solution. Hard saying, but as stated this looks more like an XY problem than anything else.

Comment: @Useless Alright, for now im not that concerned with performance. I will try this out thanks!

Comment: Your logic doesn't make sense.  Why is whether any other thread is doing productive work relevant to whether there is more productive work available to be done?